# Sightly Component Cannot Find Bundled WCMUse(Pojo)

Tags: java, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, sightly

I've been following the documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html#Bundled%20Java%20Class)

Apparently, in order to have my "use" class be visible to my Sightly component, all I need to do is use the full Class name (i.e. including the package) in my "use" statement.

```
<div data-sly-use.listChildren="com.t4g.aem.impl.usebeans.ListChildrenUseBean"><!-- Markup --></div>
```

I've followed the directions and built and deployed my bundle. My compiled class is in there (I cracked the JAR to make certain.) and still, the Sightly engine cannot find my class. I've tried WCMUse and WCMUsePojo. I've tried alternate syntaxes in the Sightly markup (I've found variants here and there). Nothing seems to works for a bundled use bean.

If I drop the same class into the component and update the package to match, everything works fine.

I'd love to know:

1. If anybody has ever actually gotten this to work
2. How to get it to work

Thank you for your help.

The exception I get is:

```
org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Identifier
com.t4g.aem.impl.usebeans.ListChildrenUseBean cannot be correctly
instantiated by the Use API

[...]

Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Cannot
find class com.t4g.aem.impl.usebeans.ListChildrenUseBean.
```

The full exception trace is as follows (it's really long, sorry):

```
org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Identifier com.t4g.aem.impl.usebeans.ListChildrenUseBean cannot be correctly instantiated by the Use API
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.UseRuntimeExtension.call(UseRuntimeExtension.java:91)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderContextImpl.call(RenderContextImpl.java:89)
at apps.noSightly.components.listchildren.SightlyJava_listchildren.render(SightlyJava_listchildren.java:41)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderUnit.render(RenderUnit.java:52)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.evaluateScript(SightlyScriptEngine.java:95)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.eval(SightlyScriptEngine.java:83)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:533)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:259)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:445)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.IncludeTagHandler.dispatch(IncludeTagHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.doEndTag(AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.java:129)
at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.parsys.parsys_jsp._jspService(parsys_jsp.java:318)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:533)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:259)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:445)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeResource(IncludeTag.java:224)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:91)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.actionaut.components.contentpage.center_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f3(center_jsp.java:258)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.actionaut.components.contentpage.center_jsp._jspService(center_jsp.java:166)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeScript(IncludeTag.java:167)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:87)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.actionaut.components.contentpage.body_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f0(body_jsp.java:190)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.actionaut.components.contentpage.body_jsp._jspService(body_jsp.java:155)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeScript(IncludeTag.java:167)
at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:87)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.actionaut.components.contentpage.contentpage_jsp._jspx_meth_cq_005finclude_005f1(contentpage_jsp.java:204)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.actionaut.components.contentpage.contentpage_jsp._jspService(contentpage_jsp.java:158)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:533)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:259)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:445)
at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:533)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:371)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:171)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:155)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:201)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:152)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:364)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:243)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.t4g.aem.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:40)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.cnb.aem.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:40)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.analytics.provisioning.impl.UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:110)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:260)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:120)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: Cannot find class com.t4g.aem.impl.usebeans.ListChildrenUseBean.
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.compiler.SightlyJavaCompilerService.getInstance(SightlyJavaCompilerService.java:126)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.JavaUseProvider.getPOJOFromRepository(JavaUseProvider.java:125)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.JavaUseProvider.provide(JavaUseProvider.java:112)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.UseRuntimeExtension.call(UseRuntimeExtension.java:87)
... 248 more
```

Comment: Is your bundle active in your OSGI console?
Can you copy paste your Java Code (part of it)?

Comment: I've figured this out now (thanks to some help). The key is to add the classes you need to access in Sightly to the exported-packages in the OSGi manifest. This can be done by editing the bundle projects pom.xml and adding them to the maven-bundle-plugin configuration. I'll post an answer below.

Comment: Usually when you cannot instantiate a class within AEM, it's either your bundle is not in "active" state in the OSGI console, which may happen if you are missing a dependency or the class is not in the bundle itself. The second option is quite rare since most of the time you will include all packages you write inside the maven bundle plugin, glad you've found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I found, thanks to some help I received elsewhere.

To avoid this issue, you need to make sure that the bundle's OSGi manifest's import-package (i.e. dependencies) and export-package (i.e. your "Use" classes) reflect the classes you want exposed to your Sightly scripts. This will allow Felix to be aware of them and inject them wherever they're needed.

Here is an example snipped from from my test code's config (i.e. myproject-bundle/pom.xml):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.us.aem.sightly-stuff-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Export-Package>
                <!-- Let's export our primary package -->
                com.us.aem.impl.usebeans
                <!-- By default, don't export any other packages -->
            </Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>

                <!-- JSR 250 && 330 -->
                javax.annotation;version=0.0.0.1_007_JavaSE,
                javax.inject,

                <!-- JEE Servlet -->
                javax.servlet,
                javax.servlet.http,

                <!-- Sling -->
                org.apache.sling.api,
                org.apache.sling.api.resource,
                org.apache.sling.auth.core,
                org.apache.sling.jcr.api,
                com.day.cq.commons, 
                org.apache.sling.api.request,
                com.adobe.cq.sightly,
                com.day.cq.wcm.api,
                org.slf4j
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The reason why I overlooked this is that this step isn't necessary for the classes I'm used to creating in bundles (e.g. OSGi services such a Servlets, Schedulers, etc.) In those, I use Felix SCR annotations that allow a different plugin to pick up the classes and add them to the manifest automatically. (I believe it is the **org.apache.felix.maven-scr-plugin** that does this.)

The bottom line is that for a class to be visible outside an OSGi bundle, it needs to be registered in the manifest. Sometimes we use **org.apache.felix.scr.annotations**, sometimes we need to explicitly tell our Maven build about them.

Hopefully this answer can be of help to people who run into this same issue. Once you know what's missing, it all makes sense.

Thanks!